# Cross compiling in Rust requires both host and target architecture dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo, tauri

I'm trying to figure out how to cross compile my Rust project to build it for ARM64. I've setup a Tauri v1 project and followed their [official documentation](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/linux/#manual-compilation) on how to configure my Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 machine to cross compile for ARM. It worked and I was very happy with my little pipeline that built my release packages in 3 minutes and not half an hour on my RPi. Here is the Action workflow for reference: [build.yml](https://github.com/krokosik/last_snow/blob/v0.3.3/.github/workflows/build.yml).

Unfortunately, due to buggy IME support, I had to upgrade to Tauri v2 alpha, to get their fix. I managed to migrate my code and build the app locally, but encountered issues with building, as the pipeline no longer worked due to changes in required system dependencies. I tried `cross-rs`, but their images are built on Ubuntu 20.04 and there are no backports of:

- `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.1-dev`
- `libsoup-3.0-dev`
- `libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev`

Then, after installing them I got more errors in my workflow. It either complained that I don't have these packages, while building crates that required them (solved by installing deps) or errored in the linking phase, where it couldn't find those dependencies, but for the ARM64 architecture. At the same time, I realized I cannot install both AMD64 and ARM64 versions, so I ended up with a working solution that first build crates with AMD64 versions installed and then using the cached files builds the final binary using the ARM64 versions.
[Working workflow](https://github.com/krokosik/last_snow/blob/v0.4.3/.github/workflows/build.yml)

It works, but takes twice as long and seems really dumb to me and as a person that is not that familiar with Cargo caveats, I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Why are the crates built using AMD64 libs if the target is specified as ARM? Why was it working before? Could it be something that the Tauri devs set up incorrectly in their Cargo manifests? I'd very grateful in helping me understand this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done much cross-compilation for Linux systems.

But based on the experience I have with macOS and different architectures, specifically `x86_64` and `arm64`, they offer three ways to do it:

```
npm run tauri build --target aarch64-apple-darwin
npm run tauri build --target x86_64-apple-darwin
npm run tauri build --target universal-apple-darwin
```

So the last one `universal-apple-darwin` behaves exactly like you describe in your question, it builds it two times, and creates [fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary) binaries.

I realize linux uses ELF binaries, so the process is slightly different.

Anyway, back to your question, there's one **workaround** I found to cut time in this architecture, is to use [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

This way if you split your application into, let's say `library` and `main` application, you won't need to recompile library each time you modify main, and vice versa.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps because all of these dependencies are specified by Tauri itself, so I cannot separate them in my code